Sum of two triangles in a projective plane modulo a conic
Given a conic $C$ in the complex projective plane, say $C=\{c:=x^2+y^2+z^2=0\}$, and two “triangles” (given as zeros of products of 3 linear forms $\ell=\{ax+by+cz\}$) $\ell_1\ell_2\ell_3$, $\ell'_1\ell'_2\ell'_3$, one can express the cubic form $q:=\ell_1\ell_2\ell_3+\ell'_1\ell'_2\ell'_3$ as $\ell''_1\ell''_2\ell''_3+\ell_0''c$.
Indeed, generically $C$ intersects $Q:=\{q=0\}$ in 6 points,
which one can partition into 3 pairs $p_{1j},p_{2j}$, $j=1,2,3$, and take $\ell''_1,\ell''_2,\ell''_3$
defined by each pair of these points: $\{\ell''_j=0\}=p_{1j}p_{2j}$. Then $q$ and $\ell''_1\ell''_2\ell''_3$ differ by an element $\ell''_0c$ of the ideal $(c)\subset\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.
My question is how to describe $\ell''_1,\ell''_2,\ell''_3$ — one of (or even all of) the $15=\binom{6}{2}$ choices — geometrically, or algebraically. Ideally, it should in terms of intersections of the triangles with $C$, and some scaling factors.

If you rescale the lines $\ell'_i$, the curve $Q$ and the lines $\ell''_i$ will change, though the conic and its intersection points with the triangles won't. This shows that you cannot expect to have an answer in terms of intersection points only.

sure, there will be some scaling factors involved, too.

How do you imagine using a scaling factor geometrically?

in my setting I can assume that there is no scaling allowed (say, all the points on C involved are given by norm 1 vectors of local coordinates). Is there a geometric framework for this?

it's probably not working the way I naively thought it could.

This is not an answer, but a reformulation of the problem, that may sheds some light on it.
Consider the variety of triangles
$$
T := \mathrm{Sym}^3\mathbb{P}^2 \subset \mathbb{P}^9
$$
inside the variety of all plane cubcis, and the plane
$$
\Pi_C := C \times \mathbb{P}^2 \subset \mathbb{P}^9
$$
of cubics proportional to $C$. Note that $\Pi_C$ does not intersect $T$. Therefore, the linear projection
$$
\pi_C \colon \mathbb{P}^9 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^6
$$
out of $\Pi_C$ induces a regular morphism
$$
T \to \mathbb{P}^6.
$$
The argument in the question shows that this morphism is generically finite of degree 15. Now, the images of the two given triangles generate a line $L \subset \mathbb{P}^6$, and (assuming that the given triangles are general) its preimage in $T$ is a smooth curve $T_L$. Then the question is to find a point in the curve $T_L$ over a given point in the line $L$.
